# Python - xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0

Tags: python, json, xml, parsing

I am trying to convert a xml file to a json file. I am doing this by using ElementTree and parsing through it. I am stuck on this error that I am getting though and I am not sure how to fix it.

xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import json

def xml_to_json(xml_file, json_file):
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    data = {}

    for elem in root:
        data[elem.tag] = elem.text

    with open(json_file, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)

xml_to_json('input.xml', 'output9999.json')
```

I tried making a UTF addition to my tree parse but I continued to get the same error. I tried using different inputs, same errors as well.

Here is the contents of my input, input.xml.

{"timestamp":"2023-03-06T00:14:52.2485541-05:00","hash":{"body_md5":"276bbb20c29087e88db63899fd8f9129","body_mmh3":"1084612514","body_sha256":"5b61b0c2032b4aa9519d65cc98c6416c12415e02c7fbbaa1be5121dc75162edb","body_simhash":"17956186510721919950","header_md5":"61236511ca06631d69ac2aa03e2b2ed6","header_mmh3":"1266527742","header_sha256":"64a1a17658580224e1a593aa079f934c0078f83da2331d3cbcb924f4930e2786","header_simhash":"9814106780755273709"},"port":"443","url":"https://google.com:443","input":"google.com","location":"https://www.google.com/","title":"301 Moved","scheme":"https","webserver":"gws","content_type":"text/html","method":"GET","host":"142.250.190.142","path":"/","time":"212.2639ms","a":["142.250.190.142","2607:f8b0:4009:802::200e"],"tech":["Google Web Server","HTTP/3"],"words":9,"lines":7,"status_code":301,"content_length":220,"failed":false}

Comment: That's not XML. It looks like JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The input you provided is not valid [XML](https://www.w3.org/XML/). It appears to be in [JSON format](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) already. If you are meaning to do the conversion in the other direction, a `json_to_xml` function might go something like:

```py
def json_to_xml(json_file, xml_file):
    with open(json_file, "r") as input_file:
        data = json.load(input_file) # `data` will be a dictionary
    
    root = ET.Element("root") # name your root element whatever you want
    for key, val in data.items():
        elem = ET.SubElement(root, key)
        if isinstance(val, (str, int)):
            elem.text = str(val)
        elif isinstance(val, dict):
            for subkey, subval in val.items():
                subelem = ET.SubElement(elem, subkey)
                subelem.text = subval
        elif isinstance(val, list):
            elem.text = " / ".join(val) # or handle lists however you want
        else:
            pass # shouldn't happen with your input as provided
            
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write(xml_file, xml_declaration=True,
               encoding="UTF-8", pretty_print=True)
```

Pasting your input into a file called `input.json` and calling `json_to_xml("input.json", "output9999.xml")` will produce a `output9999.xml` that looks like:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <timestamp>2023-03-06T00:14:52.2485541-05:00</timestamp>
  <hash>
    <body_md5>276bbb20c29087e88db63899fd8f9129</body_md5>
    <body_mmh3>1084612514</body_mmh3>
    <body_sha256>5b61b0c2032b4aa9519d65cc98c6416c12415e02c7fbbaa1be5121dc75162edb</body_sha256>
    <body_simhash>17956186510721919950</body_simhash>
    <header_md5>61236511ca06631d69ac2aa03e2b2ed6</header_md5>
    <header_mmh3>1266527742</header_mmh3>
    <header_sha256>64a1a17658580224e1a593aa079f934c0078f83da2331d3cbcb924f4930e2786</header_sha256>
    <header_simhash>9814106780755273709</header_simhash>
  </hash>
  <port>443</port>
  <url>https://google.com:443</url>
  <input>google.com</input>
  <location>https://www.google.com/</location>
  <title>301 Moved</title>
  <scheme>https</scheme>
  <webserver>gws</webserver>
  <content_type>text/html</content_type>
  <method>GET</method>
  <host>142.250.190.142</host>
  <path>/</path>
  <time>212.2639ms</time>
  <a>142.250.190.142 / 2607:f8b0:4009:802::200e</a>
  <tech>Google Web Server / HTTP/3</tech>
  <words>9</words>
  <lines>7</lines>
  <status_code>301</status_code>
  <content_length>220</content_length>
  <failed>False</failed>
</root>
```